# Get Gridview Row Index

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using the below code to get the row index

```
protected void gvESAPending_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

    {
        try
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "";
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = gvESAPending.Rows[index]; // Here incorrect format error is coming
        }
     }
```

But the index value is coming as 0. What is wrong here?

Aspx Code

'>
                                            
                                        
                                        
                                            
                                                '>

Comment: Have a look at [GridView.RowCommand Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx)

Comment: I tried the same way still no help

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Seems this event been called before the grid initialize. try using the code within `if(gvESAPending.Rows.Count>0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can add OnRowCreteEvent

ASPX:

```
<asp:gridview id="gvESAPending" onrowcreated="gvESAPending_RowCreated" ...
```

CS :

```
protected void gvESAPending_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      LinkButton addButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];

      addButton.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
    }

  }
```

Comment: I got this error
{System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.

Comment: What is the error ? Can you give us the aspx code or follow the recommendation of @huMpty duMpty

Comment: <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button"  CommandName="App" Text="Approve">
                                            <ControlStyle BackColor="White" BorderStyle="None" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="Blue" />
                                        </asp:ButtonField>
                                        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Dec" Text="Decline">
                                            <ControlStyle BackColor="White" BorderStyle="None" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="Blue" />
                                        </asp:ButtonField>

Comment: How will on rowcreate help .. I am not creating any row

Comment: Ok that why the index value is coming as 0. Can you explain what you wanna do  ??

Comment: Already the gridview is bound with data .. I am clicking a buttonfield and thus need to get the row number

Comment: gridview is bound with data so rows are created !

Comment: all the examples are showing can be achieved by gvESAPending_RowCommand, why my code is not working .. am i missing something4

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Answer (score 0):

```
GridViewRow row = gvESAPending.Rows[index];
```

By doing this your actually accessing the row at index. So if index = 2 your actually returning the third row in your gridviewrow.

Comment: int index = Convert.ToInt32( e.CommandArgument);
This is returning 0 so it should work. But its giving error

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: try this 

`Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())`

something may be screwy with the convert function, this should boil it down and give you something more useful to work with. If you really want to get fancy set

`string var = e.CommandArgument.ToString()` 

put a break point right after it and check it out in the locals window to make sure your getting a value